# Css border lines not showing when assigned to td tags in PDF file generated by DOMPDF

Tags: dompdf

I'm rendering a table using DomPDF 0.6, now I need to have borders throughout each cell. If I use  then the cellpadding and cellspacing affects the width of the border so I can't use it.

Now I have my table

```
$html = '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" width="100%" style="border:1px solid #000;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="borderOk">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="borderOk" align="center" colspan="2" style="font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;"><i>'.$pName1.'</i></td>
                    <td class="borderOk" align="center" colspan="2" style="font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;"><i>'.$pName2.'</i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="borderOk"><strong><i>Price</i></strong></td>
                    <td class="borderOk" colspan="2" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="borderOk" colspan="2" >&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="borderOk"><strong><i>Options</i></strong></td>
                    <td class="borderOk" colspan="2" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="borderOk" colspan="2" >&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="borderOk" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="borderOk" colspan="2" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="borderOk" colspan="2" >&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
</table>';
```

With my styles that look like this "Also is within the $html variable at the top"

```
<style type="text/css">

    td .borderOk{  
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-color: #A5C3E0;
}
</style>
```

The borders show perfectly in my Browser but when rendering it using domPDF the pdf file shows without the inner td borders, only the outline border is shown.

My DomPDF code looks like this

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$dompdf->load_html($_SESSION['html'],'UTF-8');
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream(date("YmdHis").".pdf");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS selector should be

```
td.borderOk
```

(without the space)

Or better : add the `borderOK` class to the table and leave your CSS as it is.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it does not work, I tried to add in inline style to the table  style="border:1px solid #000;" , this shows perfectly if I render it in a browser but does not show on the PDf file

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Remove the border="0" then do as Fabien noted: td.borderOk or just .borderOk

Answer (score 1):

Try to use dompdf version 0.6.0 beta3. It will work for sure. I had tried your code.

http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/downloads/detail?name=dompdf_0-6-0_beta3.tar.gz